# NetBeans 8.1 running the background scan forever on one project

Tags: java, scala, netbeans

I installed NetBeans 8.1 fresh on a MacBook Pro (2.8. Ghz intel Core i7, 16 GB ram, 1T SSD running Yosemite).

Running Java 1.8.0_51 and Scala 2.11.4

Installed the netbeans-sbt plugin and ran "sbt netbeans" over my existing projects.

Tweaked the netbeans Xms to 1024 and Xmx to 2048

Loaded netbeans all looked right.

Opening two of my existing projects all worked fine.  Upon opening the third and main project the background scan ran up to 100% without stopping and I eventually had to kill the two processes related to netbeans.  Upon reloading netbeans I immediately closed the offending project and the background scan completed and went away.  I reopened the project and it began running the scan and got hung at 100% just like before.  Noticed that is had a critical message that it had run out of memory.  I killed netbeans and changed the Xmx property to 4096 and started netbeans again it did the same thing with the background scan.  It reached 100% and never finished.

Not sure how to proceed.  Would like to use netbeans for my scala projects but I can't even get it to work out of the gate.  I am willing to try anything aside from swapping out the machine or throwing it out the window.

On a side note, Eclipse is working just fine as far as loading the project with settings Xms512m and Xmx2048m but has other anomalies with showing errors in the editor when the project compiles cleanly.

Would love some help.